# Issue with jekyll gem/plugin execution order, I think

Tags: plugins, rubygems, jekyll

I'm looking at implementing https://github.com/wildlyinaccurate/jekyll-responsive-image in my jekyll build. I install it as a gem.

First off - please forgive this rambling question. Secondly, I'm pretty sure this isn't an issue with the plugin but with my limited ruby knowledge but I thought I'd check.

Quick bit of background. I wrote quick and dirty generator plugin to duplicate every post but with a slightly different name for AMP (index.amp.html). It applies a different template and does some text replacement. I have another quick plugin to replace the markdown implementation of images

`![funny image](images/hello.jpg)`

to the required liquid tag for this responsive image plugin:

`{% responsive_image path: assets/my-file.jpg %}`

To the crux of my problem, it responsive image plugin doesn't apply to my plugin-generated file in my build process. Is it because of the build order (i.e. when plugins or gems get executed) or because there's some coding that I don't understand in this plugin?

To be a little clearer; So I have a index.html and index.amp.html and they both have the responsive liquid tag but only the index.html gets replaced by the plugin. Is it because the gem is executed before the plugin because the gem is more closely integrated with the actual Jekyll build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've looked at the plugin in greater detail, and I've realised I'm an idiot. Its not doing a regex find content and replace job, its actually doing the site render. So it has no idea my files exist.

I'm going to use grunt to replace this on my amp files I think. Thanks for reading.